# Emails go to spam folder on email server with MS Exchange

Tags: email, spam, block, exchange-server

Emails from redwerk.com email server goes in spam folder on server with MS Exchange. I had performed all kinds of server checkings (SPF, DKIM, Blacklists).

Had performed checkings on https://opengapps.org, https://mxtoolbox.com, https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx. I had perform delisting on https://sender.office.com/ and emails still goes in spam folder.

Do someone have any idea what other checks and steps I can perform?

Answer (score 0):

You can check several things:

- if messages from certain domain go to spam folder to all users, check your antispam options/logs (probably you have some anti-spam engine on the edge or hub server or maybe some antispam on the gateway)
- you can have some transport rules that mark certain messages with SCL:9 (spam confidence level). 9 is the highest level (probably spam)
- if this happens for a certain user, he or she could mark the sender or sender domain as junk and therefore all messages (applies to microsoft outlook client).
  You can check it with `Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration` cmdlet.
- if you have thunderbird mail client, check it's SPAM settings, it has separate anti-spam who "loves" to mark legit messages as spam